# Matlab OOP array of objects class

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop

I'd like to understand how Matlab works with array objecs. I've read several posts and the Matlab help for this topic, but I still don't understand it completely.

Let's take a use case: I'd like to manage several measurement channels (the amount of channels can vary). Each measurement channel is an object with several properties. Now I'd like to have a class handling the channels (channelHandler.m). In this class I can simply add a new channel to the array (later on there might be bore functionality).

So what I've tried so far:

1) create the measurementChannel.m class
In the constructor I've only set the channel name so far without data.

```
classdef measurementChannel
%CHANNEL holds an instance of a single channel

properties
    channelData
    channelName = strings
    channelUnit = strings
    channelDataLength    
    channelOriginMeasurementFile
end

methods
    function obj = channelTest(channelName)
        if nargin > 0
            obj.channelName = channelName;
        end
    end
end
```

end

To test this class I tried this:

```
channel(1) = measurementChannel('channelA');
channel(2) = measurementChannel('channelB');
channel(1).channelName
channel(2).channelName
```

which was working well.

2) Now I've created the channelHandler class:

```
classdef channelHandler

properties (Access = public)
    channelArray
end

methods (Access = public)

    function addChannel(obj, Name)

        testobj = measurementChannel();

        testobj.channelName = Name;

        obj.channelArray = [obj.channelArray testobj];

    end

end
```

and access this by using the following commands:

```
createChannels = channelHandler();

createChannels.addChannel('channel1');
createChannels.addChannel('channel2');

createChannels.channelArray(1).channelName
createChannels.channelArray(2).channelName
```

this fails because channelArray is not defined as an array and will give an error accessing channelArray(2).
So I also tried to initialize the array (but then I need to know the amount of channels).

so my questions are: 
a) do I really need to initialize an array of objects?
b) how can I fix the channelHandler class to add objects to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not inheriting [from the `handle` class and therefore the modifications made within `addChannel` alter a *copy* of your object rather than the object itself](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html). If you inherit from `handle`, the code that you have pasted will work just fine.

```
classdef channelHandler < handle
```

Comment: just for my understanding: If I'm using the handle class, only a reference to the object is stored in the channelArray. why is it not possible to store the data itself in the channelArray?

Comment: @Christoph The references are stored in the array, but that's effectively the same as the data itself being stored in the `channelArray`. All that it means is that if you assign it to a different variable and modify it, that change will be reflected in the original object.